# "woul rather V" in the past

Tags: modal-verbs

Is the following okay? I wouldn't consider using "would rather have stayed" because it's counteractual.

> Because it was too cold, **we'd rather stay** at home yesterday.

Comment: **Would rather have stayed** is perfectly valid, depending on what you're saying.

Comment: The phrase "would rather stay" is grammatical, but not in that context. In that context, you'd say "we'd rather have stayed," "we would've rather stayed," or "we would rather have stayed."

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't say this.

One alternative would be:

> Because it was too cold, we preferred to stay at home yesterday.